# Python write a string to a file and keep \r

Tags: python, carriage-return

In python (2.7 or 3), say I have a string with `\r` in it, and I want to write it to a file and *keep* the `\r`. The default behavior is to replace the `\r` with `\n`. How can I do this? For example:

```
f= open("file.txt","w+")
f.write('foo\rbar')
f.close()
```

Leaves me with a file with text `foo\nbar`. I've read about universal newline handling, and I think I can use `newline=''` as an option for `open()` when opening a file with `\r` if I want to keep the `\r`. But `write()` does not accept the `newline` option, and I'm at a loss.

I have an application where the `\r` is meaningful, distinct from `\n`. And I need to be able to write to file and keep `\r` as it is.

Comment: Open the file in binary mode and write like `f.write(b'foo\rbar')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode, appending a `b` to the mode you want to use.

```
with open("file.txt","wb") as f:
    f.write(b'foo\rbar')
```

It is better you use `with open...` instead of opening and closing the file by yourself.

Comment: None of the answers here are working, including this one. I'm using py 3.8. Still gives me foo<newline>bar in the file

Answer (score 0):

read and write in binary format.

```
f= open("file.txt","wb")
f.write(b'foo\rbar')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file with `newline=''` so that on output, no translation takes place. The `write` method does not have a `newline` parameter because the file object is already initialized with it:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write('foo\rbar')
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> When writing output to the stream, if `newline` is `None`, any `'\n'`
>   characters written are translated to the system default line
>   separator, `os.linesep`. If `newline` is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes
>   place.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone has their preferences apparently.

I'm just going to add an `r` to your code to make the string a raw string:

```
f= open("file.txt","w+")
f.write(r'foo\rbar') # right before the string
f.close()
```

And you are good to go.